# smartface app xcode simulator blank screen

Tags: smartface.io

I publish app on smartface for ios with the given license.
I followed the steps ios publishing guides with bundle id given by smartface.
Before submitting the appstore i want to simulate or check on the ios device but it only show black screen while lunching app.
Is it normal? Or should be run on xcode simulator or test device.

Answer (score 0):

You should always test on device.  The iOS Simulator is a great tool for rapid prototyping, bringup, and rapid iteration, but always test on device as well.  It sounds like you have a real bug in your app.

Comment: If i publish with demo licence everything is ok with bundle id "io.smartface.SmartfaceDemo" i can see app in simulator. But if i use the bundle id provided by the license it does not work.

Comment: I create a new bundle id and has solved from smartface. Probably existing one not valid.